# I have a flight booked to Germany May 7th from the U.S

Tags: air-travel, schengen, europe, visa-bans

I will be going to Berlin May 7th. Does anyone know if the borders will be open, and If I can make it there and back?

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate of one of the older questions here. I would be surprised if the flights go without problems. But the other question is, do you need to be in Germany? It is very unlikely that Germany will be back to normal by then. (A long way from normal I guess.)

Comment: None of us are any better at predicting the future than you are, especially in this situation, so whether the borders will be open, only time can tell.

Answer (score 3):

## Depends on your reason for travel.

If you ask about making it back, you are presumably not a resident in Germany. That removes one valid reason. Entry for tourism is banned right now. Entry for business may be allowed if the reason is deemed 'important.' Except for some listed cases, you might have to go into two weeks quarantine after arrival in Germany.